# How to specify a network interface with a regular public IP address instead of an EIP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template that includes an `AWS::EC2::Instance`, an `AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface`, and an `AWS::EC2::EIP`. They are all connected to each other, the network interface grabs the EIP and then gets attached to the instance, and everything works well.

Now, I want to change it so that the template doesn't create an EIP but simply creates a regular random public IP address. I could accomplish that by removing the EIP resource and specifying the `AssociatePublicIpAddress` option in the network interface. The problem is, that option is only valid for an embedded `NetworkInterface` property type, and not for a `AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface` resource. The network interface is used elsewhere (in an `AWS::EC2::Route` resource) as a reference, so I can't turn it into an embedded type. What can I do?

[EC2 instance docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-networkinterfaces)

[NetworkInterface embedded property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html)

[NetworkInterface resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you could return the random PublicIp somehow, you would add this to your route. Then you would stop/start your instance and have the IP changed. How do you expect your environment to behave in such a situation? I believe AWS prevents you from doing that to help save you from having a stall IP on the route.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) can be set to acquire a public IP address from the (non-EIP) pool but this only actually happens when the ENI has been attached to an instance and the instance is in the process of starting up.  That address is not obtained until the instance starts, and is released when the instance is stopped.  If the instance starts again, the ENI will acquire a different public address from the pool.  The process repeats each time the instance stops and starts.

ENIs with public IPs from the pool are not appropriate for this use case.

If you need more EIPs than are allowed by the default limit, you can [create a free support request](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc) and describe your use case.  There is no charge for an EIP that is attached to any running instance, as long as it is the only EIP attached to that instance.